# Looking for an alien war story where human soldiers are tricked into thinking they've died and gone to heaven

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I heard a description of a book in some behind-the-scenes footage of the film Zero Day (2003), and I was wondering if any of this sounds familiar to anyone.

In part of the book, aliens abduct the soldiers and take them to a place that they think is heaven. It looks like Earth and is filled with all of the soldiers' houses, but when they enter the house to see their families they are eaten by the aliens.

The BTS footage (the book is mentioned at timestamp 6:17):

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That sounds like [Ray Bradbury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Bradbury)'s short story ["Mars Is Heaven!"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58440), except that in Bradbury's story the Martians don't eat the Earthmen as far as we know. (They kill them in their sleep and bury them the next day.) It was first published in [*Planet Stories*, Fall 1948](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59992+c), which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Planet_Stories_Canadian_Ed._v03n12_1948-Fall/page/n57/mode/2up) along with the [*Dimension X*](https://archive.org/details/OTRR_Dimension_X_Singles/Dimension_X_1950-07-07__14_MarsIsHeaven.mp3) radio adaptation. The story was adapted to television as an episode of [The Ray Bradbury Theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ray_Bradbury_Theater), available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aOmfefUsJo&t=642s). It was included in [*The Martian Chronicles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_Chronicles), a collection of Bradbury's Mars stories which might be the "alien book" mentioned in the video, or they might be referring to any of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?58440).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Is_Heaven!) plot summary:

> It is 1986 and the third exploratory spaceship from Earth is landing on Mars. The crew is shocked to discover a Rockwellian small town, eerily similar to those they left on Earth. The strangely familiar people in the town believe it is 1926. Crew members soon discover old friends and deceased relatives in the town. Those who had been ordered to stay behind and guard the rocket abandon their posts in order to join the reunions and festivities.
>
> Members of the crew split up to spend the night in the homes of their lost comrades and relatives. The ship's captain remains skeptical, and realizes in the middle of the night that the entire situation may have been contrived by telepathic aliens to lower the Earthmen's guards. Before he can warn the others or reestablish a guard on the spaceship, he is proved right as he and the rest of the crew are killed by aliens masquerading as their family members.